# Why can't the decimal fraction part of $\frac{1}{d}$, $d \in \mathbb{N}^\ast$ have a recurring cycle of length greater than $d$?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, euclidean-algorithm

I am trying to solve [problem 26 from project euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=26) which asks *Find the value of $d < 1000$ for which $1/d$ contains the longest recurring cycle in its decimal fraction part.*

I noticed that all the cycle lengths are smaller than $d$ (at least for numbers $d < 1'000'000$), and I was wondering why this seems to be true. Is there a deep reason for this, or is this just something trivial I am not seeing?

Comment: Are you familiar with the ordinary long division algorithm? The one people might learn in school for dividing numbers by hand?

Comment: Yes I am familiar with this algorithm

Comment: Longest cycle has to do with $10$ being a primitive root of $d$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is maximum of $d-1$ possible remainders when dividing $1 \cdot 10, 2 \cdot 10 , ... (d-1) \cdot 10$ by $d$ and eventually in the process of division you divide some of these numbers with $d$ again and then all repeats.

Comment: Okay that makes sense! Thank you. I have to wait 7 min before accepting your answer. Remind me if I forget.

Comment: Wouldn't there be $d$ possible remainders when dividing $0 \cdot 10, 1 \cdot 10,...(d-1) \cdot 10$?

Comment: @GreyMatters I think that technically yes, but if the remainder is $0$, the division is over and there is no cycle, so we only have to consider non zero remainder.

Answer (score 2):

Seing as you are familiar with the long division algorithm, I'll give a reason based on that (at least the way I *hope* you're used to doing it, something similar to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icidesQM6Rw), only you keep going after the decimal point). During the long division algorithm, after you've "pulled down" all the non-zero digits, and start pulling down zeroes, note that whatever remainder you get (the result of the "subtraction" part, before you pull down the next $0$) will entirely dictate how all the rest of the divisions go. For this discussion I will assume that you've gotten to this point of the long division already (as the periodic nature won't appear until you start pulling down only $0$'s).

Say, for instance, you're calculating $10\div7$, you've gotten to the answer $1.4$, and a ramainder of $2$. You pull down a $0$, get $20$, write a $2$ in the answer, subtract $20-14 = 6$. So if one remainder is $2$, the next digit in the answer will *always* be $2$, and the next remainder will *always* be $6$.

Continuing, we see that *any time* the remainder is $6$, the next digit of the answer will be $8$ and the remainder will be $4$. And any time the remainder is $4$... I assume you can see how this continues. Whenever we reach a remainder we've had before, the pattern will start repeating.

Since we never get a remainder of $0$ (since that would mean the division doesn't give an infinite expansion), and you will never get a remainder equal to or larger than $7$ (as long as you do things corerctly), there are only $6$ possible remainders. Which means that the repeating pattern of remainders, and therefore the repeating pattern of decimals in the answer, can at most be $6$ long.

This discussion will, of course, work for any other number than $7$ as well. Note, however, that this does not prove that the expansion will *always* be $d-1$ long. Only that $d-1$ is the longest it can possibly get.

For instance, with $d = 9$, the remainder never changes (at least in base ten). If you are calculating $10\div 9$, and you've gotten to $1.1$ with a remainder of $1$, you pull down a $0$, get the next digit $1$, and a remainder of $1$ again. The pattern jsut repeats immediately.